# Ansible adhoc command with sudo

Tags: linux, ansible, orchestration, ansible-ad-hoc

I'm tried to execute this command:

```
ansible somegroup -m raw -a "docker ps -a" --ask-pass -K --become-user root
```

But the error is:

> Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon
>   socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock:

How to correct set directives of ansible adhoc to execute under root using `sudo su -`?

Comment: I think `--become-user root` should have done the trick? Are you sure the Docker daemon is running?

Comment: yeah. I am sure.

Comment: Wait... you gotta actually add `--become`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forgot to use `--become` switch:

```
ansible somegroup -m raw -a "docker ps -a" --ask-pass -K --become
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ansible somegroup -m raw -a "docker ps -a" --ask-pass -K --become
```

-m = This is raw,

-a = To run ad-hoc command,

--ask-pass = ssh password,

-K --become = To become root or sudo,

You can read more on ["How to use Ansible"](http://testertechie.com/how-to-use-ansible/)

Answer (score -1):

```
ansible somegroup -b -m raw -a "docker ps -a"
```

Comment: Although the code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the problem is and **how** the code helps.